# create package using Nokia IDE for Java ME (Eclipse) v3

Tags: java-me

I have developed a J2ME applciation using Nokia IDE for Java ME (Eclipse) v3 and it works fine in the emulator. I use the export command to create jad and jar files. 
However each time I send to nokia for verification it is either corrupt or says "application cannot open".
Does is have to do with signing or the IDE is the problem when exporting?

Please help

Comment: In my experience with Nokia devices, that error is usually caused by non-supported JAD/MANIFEST attributes. Very ironically, a lot of Nokia-specific attributes, that are very beneficial on SOME Nokia devices, will result in the MIDlet not being installable on other Nokia devices. Very illogical and rather poor design by Nokia in my opinion, but there you have it. So if I were you I'd start by trying to delete all non-standard JAD/MANIFEST attributes in your Project Properties, including Nokia-specific ones.

Comment: Thanks you.I think I should try developing for nokia lumia .how is it compared to s40 series platform?

Comment: Afaik Lumia is a Windows Phone, so JavaME is not supported. (Well there might be emulators by now, like there is for Android, but you'll have to look into that).
Generally you can do much more with all the new smartphones like Androids, iPhones, Windows Phones. They're faster, offers a lot more APIs, and a lot more options.
With JavaME it was easier to target the majority, since virtually all devices prior to the new smartphones, could run JavaME. Not so anymore sadly. So nowadays you kinda have to learn a lot of different languages in order to target the majority - OR you can go with Webapps.